# search on string with array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**search on string with array with javascript**

i have a string, i need to search on it with array.

for ex.

```
// that is array what i have
var arr = ['egypt', 'london', 'spain'];

// that is strings what i have
var str = "hello from egypt";
var str2 = "hello from london and spain";
```

ex. for first string, i need to now if it contain any values from array, and get it.

like : // found one value 'egypt' on str.
like : // found two values 'london, spain' on str2.

Comment: What did you try so far? It seems very basic.

Comment: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `includes` to see if array elements exist in the string or not
Here's the code that resolves your problem

```js
// that is array what i have
var arr = ['egypt', 'london', 'spain'];

// that is strings what i have
var str1 = "hello from egypt";
var str2 = "hello from london and spain";


function searchWords(str){
var res="";
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
if (str.includes(arr[i])){
res+= arr[i] +' '
}
}
console.log('found one value '+res )
}

searchWords(str1);
searchWords(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // that is array what i have
var arr = ['egypt', 'london', 'spain'];

// that is strings what i have
var str = "hello from egypt";
var str2 = "hello from london and spain";

function search_in_string(_string, _array){
 var out_arr=[];
 for(var key in _array){
  if(_string.indexOf(_array[key]) !=-1){
   out_arr.push(_array[key]);
  }
 }
 return out_arr;
}

console.log(search_in_string(str, arr));
console.log(search_in_string(str2, arr));
```